# how to send this parameters by using alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

I want to send these parameters by using **Alamofire**, but the problem is inside the parameters there is a `String` array called `person`. How do I convert it to a `Dictionary` to be able to send it?

Here are the parameters to send:

```
{
  "BRANCH_ID" : 23,
  "PACKAGE_ID": 10,
  "ARRIVE_TIME_ID": 7,
  "ARRIVE_DATE" : "12/2/2014",
  "IS_TABLE" : true,
  "IS_TICKET" : false,
  "NOTE": "hi",
  "persons": "[{
    \"ID\":\" 1\",
    \"FIRST_NAME\":\"Ali\",
    \"LAST_NAME\":\"Ahmed\",
    \"GENDER\":\"Male\",
    \"EMAIL\":\"mz_@.fgj\",
    \"FACEBOOK_URL\":\"www.google.com\",
    \"IS_MEMBER\":\"true\",
    \"IS_BOOKER\":\"true\"  
  }]",
  "addons": "[]"
}
```

What I have so far:

```
let url = URLs.addPlaceBooking
let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Content-type": "application/json"]
let paramters : [String : Any ] = [
    "BRANCH_ID" : "23",
    "PACKAGE_ID": "10",
    "ARRIVE_TIME_ID": "12",
    "ARRIVE_DATE" : "12/2/2014",
    "IS_TABLE" : true,
    "IS_TICKET" : false ,
    "NOTE": "",
    "persons" : [
        "ID": "1",
        "FIRST_NAME":"Ali",
        "LAST_NAME":"Ahmed",
        "GENDER":"Male",
        "MOBILE":"0111281456",
        "EMAIL":"mz_@.fgj",
        "FACEBOOK_URL":"www.google.com",
        "IS_MEMBER": true,
        "IS_BOOKER": true],
        "addons": []
    ]
]

Alamofire.request(url, method: .post , parameters:  paramters, encoding: URLEncoding.default , headers: headers).responseJSON { respons  in
    switch respons.result {
        case .success(let value ): print(value)
        case .failure(let error): print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you also post what have you tried so far?

Comment: @AhmadF  I have added

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue is `persons` parameter is an array of dictionaries (each dictionary represents a person); Based on the `paramters` you implemented in your code:

```
let paramters : [String : Any ] = [
    "BRANCH_ID" : "23",
    "PACKAGE_ID": "10",
    "ARRIVE_TIME_ID": "12",
    "ARRIVE_DATE" : "12/2/2014",
    "IS_TABLE" : true,
    "IS_TICKET" : false ,
    "NOTE": "",
    "persons" : [ "ID": "1",
                  "FIRST_NAME":"Ali",
                  "LAST_NAME":"Ahmed",
                  "GENDER":"Male",
                  "MOBILE":"0111281456",
                  "EMAIL":"mz_@.fgj",
                  "FACEBOOK_URL":"www.google.com",
                  "IS_MEMBER": true,
                  "IS_BOOKER": true] ,
    "addons": []
]
```

you are implementing `persons` as a *single* dictionary instead of an array of dictionaries.

The fix is to declare `person` as an array which contains a single dictionary, as:

```
let paramters : [String : Any ] = [
    "BRANCH_ID" : "23",
    "PACKAGE_ID": "10",
    "ARRIVE_TIME_ID": "12",
    "ARRIVE_DATE" : "12/2/2014",
    "IS_TABLE" : true,
    "IS_TICKET" : false ,
    "NOTE": "",
    "persons" : [[ "ID": "1",
                  "FIRST_NAME":"Ali",
                  "LAST_NAME":"Ahmed",
                  "GENDER":"Male",
                  "MOBILE":"0111281456",
                  "EMAIL":"mz_@.fgj",
                  "FACEBOOK_URL":"www.google.com",
                  "IS_MEMBER": true,
                  "IS_BOOKER": true]] ,
    "addons": []
]
```

*Aside note: it should be "parameters" instead of "paramters"*

Comment: @Sekiz would you explain what's the issue?

Comment: @Ahmed F when I did that request in postman works perfectly with this form "persons": "[{\"ID\":\" 1\",\"FIRST_NAME\":\"Ali\", \"LAST_NAME\":\"Ahmed\",\"GENDER\":\"Male\",\"EMAIL\":\"mz_@.fgj\",
  \"FACEBOOK_URL\":\"www.google.com\",
  \"IS_MEMBER\":\"true\" ,
  \"IS_BOOKER\":\"true\"  
 }]". now I want to convert this persons array to be able to send  it with the request by the way the array of persons is sting

Comment: @Sekiz what I answered should it be the form you've been asked for... Try to change the encoding to `JSONEncoding.default` instead of `URLEncoding.default`.

Answer (score 0):

In the JSON, `"person"` has a string value, not an array of objects, and `"addons"` has a string value also. I don't think this is what you want, but here is how to get it in Swift.

```
let json: [String: Any] = ["BRANCH_ID": 23, "PACKAGE_ID": 10,
                           "ARRIVE_TIME_ID": 7,
                           "ARRIVE_DATE" : "12/2/2014",
                           "IS_TABLE" : true,
                           "IS_TICKET" : false,
                           "NOTE": "hi",
                           "persons": "[{ " + // <-- Multi-line string not array of objects
                            "\"ID\":\" \"1\", " +
                            "\"FIRST_NAME\":\"Ali\", " +
                            "\"LAST_NAME\":\"Ahmed\", " +
                            "\"GENDER\":\"Male\", " +
                            "\"EMAIL\":\"mz_@.fgj\", " +
                            "\"FACEBOOK_URL\":\"www.google.com\", " +
                            "\"IS_MEMBER\":\"true\", " +
                            "\"IS_BOOKER\":\"true\" " +
                            "}]", // <-- end of Multi-line string
                           "addons": "[]"] // <-- String not array

let string = try! String(data: JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: .prettyPrinted), encoding: .utf8)!
print(string)
```